# undefined object parameter in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here is my code in javascript.

```
$('#destination_table').delegate('.destination', 'change', function () {
    var url = "/Transactions/getDestination";
    var getIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(getIndex);
    name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: { name: name },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // returns [Object] with length 1
            alert(data.geo); //alerts undefined.
            $('.destination_type' + getIndex).val(data.type); //not showing any
            $('.destination_geo' + getIndex).val(data.geo); //not showing 

        },
        error: function (err) {
            //    alert(err);
        }

    });
});
```

My Console displays an Object from the ASP.NET MVC5 Controller  `return Json(dest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` but when i call some parameter/field in the object ( `data.type` ) in the `success` it results as undefined.

from console in my client looks like this

```
  0: Object
    DestinationID: 7
    dateAdded: "/Date(1444406400000)/"
    dateLastModified: "/Date(1444406400000)/"
    geo: "USA"
    name: "China"
    type: "international"
    visaRequired: true
    winterDateFrom: "/Date(1444406400000)/"
    winterDateTo: "/Date(1444406400000)/"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
```

additional info.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult getDestination(Destination destination)
{
// var dest = db.Destination.Find(destination.DestinationID);
var dest = db.Destination.Where(x => x.name == destination.name).ToList();
return Json(dest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

when i use the `Find` Linq function the i dont have any problem.but when i change it Linq Query to `Where`. it started the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your controller is returning a list which in turn is an array at client side, you need to access its properties using its `index`:-

```
data[0].geo;
$('.destination_type' + getIndex).val(data[0].type); 
$('.destination_geo' + getIndex).val(data[0].geo);
```

and so on.

If you need just the first object then better to return single object from server using `First` or `FirstOrDefault` method.

```
var dest = db.Destination.First(x => x.name == destination.name);
```

After making this change you can access the properties directly like this:-

```
 $('.destination_type' + getIndex).val(data.type);
 $('.destination_geo' + getIndex).val(data.geo);
```

But if you want to bind multiple values then you can use a `for` loop at client side and let the server side code remain as it is.

Comment: thanks it answers my question. but is there a way i can use `Where` where i dont use any indexing in the jquery?.

Comment: @YuukkaLimson - Yes you can use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` (in this case it will return null for no match) instead of `Where` as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @YuukkaLimson or `FirstOrDefault` for case when request can return nothing

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks for the fast response rahul. im fairly new to asp.net an im having fun coding with it. thanks again!